# Swap positions of pivot table column headers

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I would like to swap the positions of pivot table column headers

Based on the screenshot:

The column headers belong to the "Quote Type" column.

I would like column header TYPE 1 to be on the left of column header TYPE 2, which in turn will be on the left of column header TYPE 3.

Ignore the blanks.

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do this once you can just drag the headers manually but with VBA you can do something like the below:

```
    With Sheets("YourSheet").PivotTables("YourPivotTable").PivotFields("Quote Type")
        .PivotItems("TYPE 1").Position = 1
        .PivotItems("TYPE 2").Position = 2
        .PivotItems("TYPE 3").Position = 3
    End With
```

Don't forget to replace YourSheet with the name of the worksheet with your pivot table and YourPivotTable with the name of your pivot table!

Note: This will give an error if one of these types isn't in the pivot table. You can add On Error Resume Next before it if you would like or make a custom error handler for it. Please let me know if this is something you need.

Comment: Perfect! This was what I needed! Many thanks!